# Plantilla Joomla

Tags: joomla3

¿Es posible añadir una página que he creado yo el contenido entero en PHP añadirle la plantilla de Joomla?
Es decir, tengo una web creada por Joomla, y un elemento del menú apunta a un archivo PHP que yo mismo he creado, pero no quiero integrarla a través de ninguna extensión, solo saber si es posible el poder añadirle el CSS de dicha plantilla a esta parte que ingreso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues esa es la finalidad de los CSS darle consistencia al diseño

solo agrega en el `<head>` de tu PHP

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

donde style.css es tu archivo css